# How can I log out of Stack Overflow website

Tags: support, logout

I login Stack Overflow with a Google Account, but I can not find a button or link to let me log out.
The only way I got so far is clear my browser's cookie...

Do any guys know about it? Thanks.

Comment: Questions about how StackOverflow itself works belong on [meta]. This site is for programming and programmers tools questions. The [help] has more information about the types of questions you should ask here. :-)

Comment: hi @KenWhite , got it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

click stack Exchange word left upper of the site the click logout